# Is it better to have int joins instead of string columns?

Tags: sql, database-design, database-normalization

Let's say I have a User which has a status and the user's status can be 'active', 'suspended' or 'inactive'.

Now, when creating the database, I was wondering... would it be better to have a column with the string value (with an enum type, or rule applied) so it's easier to both query and know the current user status or are joins better and I should join in a UserStatuses table which contains the possible user statuses?

Assuming, of course statuses can not be created by the application user.

**Edit:** Some clarification

1. I would **NOT** use string joins, it would be a int join to UserStatuses PK
2. My primary concern is performance wise
3. The possible status **ARE STATIC** and will **NEVER** change

Comment: enum as column type, is this possible? On the question front, I would not recommend string joins, you can always create a reference table with id/name, and then join on the ids, can always select the name for readability.

Comment: MySQL has enum columns. SQL Server has something similiar where you define allowed string values.

Comment: having string column as PK will slow you down a bit, when joining, comparison is happening, comparing two strings will take more time than numeric columns, BTW internal functionality of modern RDBMS will overcome part of it, the tangible performance comparison will be inserting or updating.

Comment: Any way, I'm not gonna use strings as PK's. They are just values of a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most systems it makes little or no difference to performance.  Personally I'd use a short string for clarity and join that to a table with more detail as you suggest.

```
create table intLookup
(
pk integer primary key,
value varchar(20) not null
)
insert into intLookup (pk, value) values
(1,'value 1'),
(2,'value 2'),
(3,'value 3'),
(4,'value 4')

create table stringLookup
(
pk varchar(4) primary key,
value varchar(20) not null
)

insert into stringLookup (pk, value) values
(1,'value 1'),
(2,'value 2'),
(3,'value 3'),
(4,'value 4')



create table masterData
(
stuff varchar(50),
fkInt integer references intLookup(pk),
fkString varchar(4)references stringLookup(pk)
)
create index i on masterData(fkInt)
create index s on masterData(fkString)

insert into masterData
(stuff, fkInt, fkString)
select COLUMN_NAME, (ORDINAL_POSITION %4)+1,(ORDINAL_POSITION %4)+1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
go 1000
```

This results in 300K rows.

```
select 
*
from masterData m inner join intLookup i on m.fkInt=i.pk

select 
*
from masterData m inner join stringLookup s on m.fkString=s.pk
```

On my system (SQL Server) 
- the query plans, I/O and CPU are identical
- execution times are identical.
- The lookup table is read and processed once (in either query)

There is ***NO*** difference using an int or a string.

Comment: Will not be true for tables with millions of records, frequent queering, and tight response time requirements. Just think of eBay or Amazon users.

Comment: @PM77-1 what would you suggest?

Comment: @svallory - I believe that the decision whether to normalize one's database and, if so, to which form, is important only for fairly large data sets and should be made based on operational environment requirements.  If you need split second response times to a myriad of concurrent requests you will use a lower form or no normalization at all.  That will somewhat complicate maintenance and require more storage space, but you do what you have to in such environments. If it's an average business application that works interactively with a limited number of users, go for 2nd or 3rd form.

Comment: Measure it and see.  I doubt it would make very much difference to actual, real-world examples as typically values are cached and you only use a subset for a given query.  I'd start at 3rd normal form by default.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. BTW, I don't have any extra info, only a string value, so I don't even need a join to a "stringLookup" table.

Comment: Whether you have a lookup or not (in which case make sure you use CHECK constraint), this question comes up so many times and is typically answered with so much disinformation that I finally had to do something about it!

Answer (score 2):

I think, as a whole, everyone has hit on important components of the answer to your question. However, they all have good points which should be taken together, rather than separately.

1. As logixologist mentioned, a healthy amount of Normalization is generally considered to increase performance. However, in contrast to logixologist, I think your situation is the perfect time for normalization. Your problem seems to be one of normalization. In this case, using a numeric key as Santhosh suggested which then leads back to a code table containing the decodes for the statuses will result in less data being stored per record. This difference wouldn't show in a small Access database, but it would likely show in a table with millions of records, each with a status.
2. As David Aldridge suggested, you might find that normalizing this particular data point will result in a more controlled end-user experience. Normalizing the status field will also allow you to edit the status flag at a later date in one location and have that change perpetuated throughout the database. If your boss is like mine, then you might have to change the Status of Inactive to Closed (and then back again next week!), which would be more work if the status field was not normalized. By normalizing, it's also easier to enforce referential integrity. If a status key is not in the Status code table, then it can't be added to your main table.
3. If you're concerned about the performance when querying in the future, then there are some different things to consider. To pull back status, if it's normalized, you'll be adding a join to your query. That join will probably not hurt you in any sized recordset but I believe it will help in larger recordsets by limiting the amount of raw text that must be handled. If your primary concern is performance when querying the data, here's a great resource on how to optimize queries: http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/t-sql-where/ and I think you'll find that a lot of the rules discussed here will also apply to any inclusion criteria you enforce in the join itself.

Hope this helps!

Christopher

Comment: Point by point... 

1. having a string column status doesn't break any normalization rules since the data would not be replicated and **user** status would not be reused in any other table.

2. Not the point, since in this case the table is already normalized and two, as I said, the data won't change, so it's no benefit to the "end-user experience"

3. You are getting closer here :) I'll take a look at the site you pointed out and see if it has some benchmark of a situation like mine.

Thanks!

Comment: I've only been working with SQL for a little over a year now and still have a lot to learn, so this was a good thought exercise!

Answer (score 1):

The whole idea behind normalization is to keep the data from repeating (well at least one of the concepts).

In this case there is only 1 status a user at one time (I assume) can have so their is no reason to put it in its own table. You would simply complicate things. The only reason you would have a seperate table is if for some reason these statuses were not static. Meaning next month you may add "Sort of Active" and "Maybe Inactive". This would mean changing code to make up for that if you didnt put them in their own table. You could create a maintenace page where users could add statuses and then that would require you to create a seperate table.

Comment: I don't really follow your logic. Are you saying that static, non-changing data should not be stored in tables? If I want a list of countries with their ISO codes, should I not use a separate table?

Comment: @ypercube, since countries would have attributes of their own they don't really fit the case. Also, countries can be created and destroyed :)

Comment: And how do you suggest that the OP enforces integrity on the `Status` column? With a `CHECK` constraint?

Comment: It will depend on the engine, but I can use an enum column on MySQL or a Rule on SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

An issue to consider is whether these status values have attributes of their own.

For example, perhaps you would want to have a default sort order that is different from the alphabetical order of the status text. You might also want to treat two of the statuses in a particular way that you do not treat the other, and that could be an attribute.

If you have a need for that, or suspect a future need for that, then move the status text to a different table and use an integer key value for them.

Comment: Please, assume I won't need any of that. If it was a possibility the solution would be obvious and the current wouldn't make sense at all.

Comment: Quite possibly so, but consider that these are answers that are meant to have a usage wider than your individual situation.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Integer values like 0, 1, 2. If this is fixed. When interpreting the results in Reports we can change these status back to strings.

Comment: I doubt you'd notice any difference at all using integers v strings other than when you, as a developer or support guy, look at the data in the database and you can't understand it as well.

Comment: I think integers comparison should be faster than string comparisons. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Do you think or do you know?  Measure it and find out.